# Relative imports and py2app?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, py2app

Here's how my files are laid out:

```
| setup.py
+ myapp
  | __init__.py
  | myapp.py
  | version.py
```

(Hope that's clear... not too complicated, I don't think.)

Here's what myapp.py contains:

```
from fingui   import Label
from .version import __version__

Label('I am version: ' + __version__)
```

If I'm in the directory where I can see `setup.py`, the following works fine:

```
python -m myapp.myapp
```

When I try packaging it up as an app using this:

```
python setup.py py2app
```

And then running it, I get this error message on the line where I import the version:

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Here's the contents of `setup.py`:

```
exec(open('myapp/version.py').read())

from setuptools import setup

setup(app                = 'myapp/myapp.py',
      setup_requirements = ['py2app'],
      name               = 'MyApp',
      version            = __version__)
```

If I look into the app bundle that `py2app` has generated, I see `myapp.py` is placed in the bundle, but `version.py` and `__init__.py` are nowhere to be found.

What is the proper way to structure my files? How can I get `py2app` and/or `setup` to recognize which files are necessary and where to put them?

Also, while we're on the subject, how do I get it to include fingui? That's a library that I've installed using pip... I think `py2app` might be mistaking it for a standard library module or something, so not including it in my app bundle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix this with the following:

```
| main.py   <- New file I added - details below.
| setup.py  <- I changed a bit in here.
+ myapp     <- Same exact contents as before - I changed nothing.
```

I created a new file, `main.py` which lived outside of the `myapp` package. In `setup.py`, I told it that `main.py` was the app, and that `myapp` was a package.

Contents of `main.py`:

```
from myapp import myapp
```

That's it.

New contents of `setup.py`, with comments on the changed lines.

```
exec(open('myapp/version.py').read())

from setuptools import setup

setup(app                = 'main.py',  ### This now points at main.py instead of myapp/myapp.py
      options            = {'py2app': {'packages': ['myapp']}}, ### This line is all new.
      setup_requirements = ['py2app'],
      name               = 'MyApp',
      version            = __version__)
```

I still have the problem that it doesn't seem to be copying `myapp` or `fingui` into the actual `MyApp.app` bundle... I think it's relying on `MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/site.pyc`... which will obviously break if I try to distribute my app.

Answer (score -1):

Try importing the package this way: import fingui instead of from fingui import *

Comment: It's the version import having a problem, not fingui.